# Ipad - actionsheet not showing all buttons in landscape mode when keyboard is present

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an Ipad application. It supports both landscape and portrait mode.
The app has keyboard.It also shows an action sheet with 4 buttons when required.
In portrait mode it works perfectly. But in landscape mode action sheet only show 2 buttons
when keyboard is there .Without keyboard it show all 4 buttons.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the actionsheet doesnt have a textfield or anything to type in, dont display the keyboard. If you need the keyboard after you dismiss the actionsheet, then display the keyboard in your actionsheet dismiss delegate.